# rsync in bash not parsing php-generated --exclude-from file

Tags: php, bash, rsync

My rsync bash script isn't parsing my --exclude-from file that's generated via php, but it will if I manually create (as root) the same exact file locally. I've got a web interface on a Xubuntu 12.10 system that writes rsync --exclude-from files locally and then pushes them via rcp to our (CentOS 6) backup boxes that run the rsync script. (Please spare finger wagging about rcp... I know--don't have a choice in this case.)

Webpage writes file:

PHP:

```
file_put_contents($exclfile, $write_ex_val);
```

then pushes to the backup box from a local bash script on the webserver with:

Bash:

```
rcp -p /path/to/file/${servername}_${backupsource}.excl ${server}:/destination/path
```

I've compared the permissions and ownership of the hand-created file (that works) with the same file that's php/rcp'd (that doesn't), and they're both the same:

Bash:

```
stat -c '%a' server_backupsource_byhand.excl 
644

stat -c '%a' server_backupsource_byphp.excl 
644

ls -l server_backupsource_byhand.excl 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6 May 11 05:57 server_backupsource_byhand.excl 

ls -l server_backupsource_byphp.excl 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6 May 11 05:58 server_backupsource_byphp.excl
```

In case it's relevant, here's my rsync line:

BASH:

```
rsync -vpaz -v --exclude-from=${exclfile} /mnt/${smbdir} /backup
```

I suspect php might be writing the file in a different format (e.g. UTF8 instead of ANSI), but I can't figure out how to test this, and have limited knowledge here.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get the php/rcp generated file to parse?

Comment: Forgot to include the PHP that really writes the file: $write_ex_val .= "$smbdir/$ex_name \r\n";    Maybe it's adding in trailing spaces?

Comment: Tried trimming the line in PHP before it writes to the file using trim($write_ex_val_trim) and then writing that variable in the code above and that didn't work either.

Comment: Try running `file` on the respective files, that can give you clues as to the encoding. Also try simply comparing the respective files with a `diff`, maybe that will help locating the differences.

Comment: That was really helpful, @earl, thank you. Using diff and file I found out that the php-written version wasn't writing the newline. In my variable definition I was using a "." with $write_ex_val . Removing this let php write the new lines.

Answer (score 0):

Using diff and file I found out that the php-written version wasn't writing the newline. In my variable definition I was using a "." as "$write_ex_val ." Removing this "." let php write the new lines. I also removed the space between the variable and "\n", although I'm not sure if this contributed to the solution. I'd upvote the comment, Earl, but I don't think I have enough rep. Thanks again.